# Loading a ogr data object into a geodataframe

Tags: python, geopandas, ogr

I have been experimenting with ways to work with large datasets in python and I started using ogr method of loading a layer with an sql query to speed up data access as oppose to loading the entire feature layer. I seem to have successfully got a sql layer but cannot figure out how to get it into geopandas dataframe for the rest of the process.

```
import geopandas as gpd, pandas as pd, fiona
from osgeo import ogr

gpkg_source = r"C:\...\mygeopackage.gpkg"
trackslayer = 'mygpkglayername'

layer = fiona.open(gpkg_source, layer=trackslayer)
layercrs = ((int(str(layer.crs['init']).replace('epsg:','')))) #this just returns the crs of the layer

idnum = 209204000 ##search variable for the sql expression
sql_layer = ogr.Open(gpkg_source, update=False).ExecuteSQL("SELECT * FROM "+ trackslayer+" WHERE idnum = '"+str(idnum)+"'")
print(sql_layer) ##prints some ogr stuff
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame... ##Not sure what to do here...
```

I tried a number of ways I thought my work GeoDataFrame.fromLayer or loading it in as I would a geopackage. How do I bring this ogr datatype into geopandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export your selection to an in-memory geojson (or geopackage or some other format inc. shapefile if you must) and read that with GeoPandas.

Note use of newer (gdal 2+) `gdal.OpenEx` syntax instead of the older (gdal 1x) `ogr.Open`.

e.g.

```
from osgeo import gdal
import geopandas as gpd

gpkg_source = r"test.gpkg"
trackslayer = 'test'
select_field = "id"
mempath = "/vsimem/test.geojson"  # in-memory geojson
# mempath = "/vsimem/test.gpkg"  # in-memory geopackage

ds = gdal.OpenEx(gpkg_source, gdal.OF_READONLY)
gdal.VectorTranslate(mempath, ds, SQLStatement=f"SELECT * FROM {trackslayer} WHERE {select_field} = 1", layerName=trackslayer)

# show that there's multiple features in original gpkg
gdf = gpd.read_file(gpkg_source)
print(f"input:\n{gdf.head()}\n") 

# show that there's just one feature in output
gdf = gpd.read_file(mempath)
print(f"output:\n{gdf.head()}")
```

Output:

```
input:
   id                                           geometry
0   1  MULTIPOLYGON (((130.42392 -24.43079, 136.01693...
1   2  MULTIPOLYGON (((117.08060 -24.99009, 121.15550...

output:
   id                                           geometry
0   1  MULTIPOLYGON (((130.42392 -24.43079, 136.01693...
```

Comment: This worked well for me to query out the features I needed to work with as oppose to loading the whole featureclass into the geodataframe. It took almost 20min to load all the features vs the few seconds it took to load in only those fitting the SQL statement. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This works with the pyogrio engine (https://pyogrio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pyogrio.read_dataframe) and the current version of geopandas.

It can also work with fiona 1.9+ (https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/pull/1097)
and this PR (https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/2552)

```py
import geopandas

gpkg_source = r"C:\...\mygeopackage.gpkg"
trackslayer = 'mygpkglayername'
idnum = 209204000  #search variable for the sql expression

gdf = geopandas.read_file(
    gpkg_source,
    layer=trackslayer,
    where="idnum = '"+str(idnum)+"'"
)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I didn't think this was going to happen based on this [old ticket](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/59#issuecomment-23503835).