# Converting OGR layer into GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, ogr, shapely

I have a huge Geopackage (20 GB), and I want to read in a small subset without overloading my memory. I've figured out how to do this using the Geopackage's Rtree:

```py
# Point to huge Geopackage
gpkg = ogr.Open("C:/example/my_geopackage.gpkg", update=False)

# Get subset of features using Rtree
sql = "SELECT * FROM rtree_layer_geom AS r WHERE r.miny < 100"
subset = gpkg.ExecuteSQL(sql)

subset.__class__
```

This gives me a `<class 'osgeo.ogr.Layer'>` with the correct feature count.

From here I'd like to intersect some of the geometry to some polygons in `geopandas` and `shapely`. How can I convert the `osgeo.ogr.Layer` into this format?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/440820/2856